# How to display data from response in html canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am trying to display a response fetched from an api in a html canvas, but for some reason the canvas does not display the text from the response. I inspected the element I can see in the dev tools that the data is displayed in the html but I can't see it on the screen, why is the data not visible and how can I display it properly in the canvas?

Here is my html:

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>

    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

and my js:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

canvas.width = 934;
canvas.height = 622;

var background = new Image();
background.src = 'assets/background.jpg';

background.onload = function () {
    ctx.drawImage(background, 0, 0);
}

fetch('https://api/list')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => canvas.innerHTML = data.animals.name[0]);
```

I tried to display it using the fillText() method but it didn't work as well.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You can use a [stack snippet](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269753/9253414) (`<>` in the editor).

Comment: What makes you think setting `innerHTML` of canvas would draw anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [fillText](https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_canvas_tut_text) method to draw text. And also, you made a typo. You have to use the context `ctx` where as you used the element `canvas`.

Change the line `canvas.innerHTML = data.animals.name[0]` to `ctx.fillText(data.animals.name[0], 10, 50)`